# Duplicate detection based on values stored in multiple python lists

Tags: python, list, set

I have 3 separate python lists that can store variable values depending on the time when script runs, for example:

```
requestId=[123, 456, 789, 987, 654, 321]
requestTitle=['Title1', 'Title1', 'Title2', 'Title3', 'Title3', 'Title3']
requestBodyText=['BodyText1', 'BodyText1', 'BodyText2', 'BodyText3', 'BodyText3', 'BodyText3']
```

I need to distinguish which requests are duplicated and which are unique based on `requestTitle` and `requestBodyText` (if request has identical requestTitle and requestBody then it is a duplicate), for the above it would be then:

```
uniqueList=[123,789,987]
duplicateList=[456, 654, 321]
```

once I know this then I need to pair requestIds in order to pass values to my `for loop` in `emails.py` as `x` (unique) and `y` (duplicate) variables. My goal here is to relate all the duplicate to unique requests via API.

After pairing results should look as follows:

```
uniqueIds =[123, 987, 987]
duplicateIds=[456, 654, 321]
```

987 appears twice, because it has two duplicate emails 654 and 321. So it has to run two times to relate both requests (654 and 321) see below:

emails.py:

```
HOST = 'https://myUrl.com/path/'

def update_request(request, token, userid):
    headers = {     'accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'my-token': token,
                    'User-ID': userid}
    endpoint = 'request/'
    body = {'requestId': x, "addRelatedEmails": [{"id": duplicatedEmailId, "name": "EMAIL"}]}
    return requests.put(url = HOST + endpoint, headers = headers, json=body, verify=False)
    print(r.text)
    return True

for x, y in zip(uniqueIds, duplicateIds):
    update_requests(x, token, userid, duplicatedEmailId=y)
```

Not sure if the above is doable in a way I'm describing here, but maybe someone would be able to help with this or suggest easier solution? Thanks in advance.

To @Cireo:

```
requestId=[123, 456, 789, 987, 654, 321]
requestTitle=['Title1', 'Title1', 'Title2', 'Title3', 'Title3', 'Title3']
requestBodyText=['BodyText1', 'BodyText1', 'BodyText2', 'BodyText3', 'BodyText3', 'BodyText3']


from collections import defaultdict
groups = defaultdict(list)  
for i, low, up in zip(requestId, requestTitle, requestBodyText): 
   groups[(low, up)].append(i)
```

When I call `groups` I'll get this (which seems like a half way to my goal):

```
groups
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {('Title1', 'BodyText1'): [123, 456], ('Title2', 'BodyText2'): [789], ('Title3', 'BodyText3'): [987, 654, 321]})
```

but now I need to do the following:

```
uniqueIds = [123, 987, 987] #here I list IDs to my requests that are duplicated. What is important I need to store them as many times as they duplicate. So 123 has one duplicate, 987 has two duplicates therefore I listed this twice.

duplicateIds=[456, 654, 321] #here only the duplicates that I need to relate to my uniqueIds.
```

So once I pass `uniqueIds` along with `duplicateIds` to my for loop it should relate:

Request 123 with Request 456

Request 987 with Request 654

Request 987 with Request 321

I'm ignoring request 789 as it has no duplicate.

Comment: You should consider creating an class to represent a request, e.g. Request(id, title, text). This will help to avoid problems, such as a bug in your code resulting in a missing element in one of your 3 lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Simplification

```
requestId=[123, 456, 789, 987, 654, 321]
requestTitle=['Title1', 'Title1', 'Title2', 'Title3', 'Title3', 'Title3']
requestBodyText=['BodyText1', 'BodyText1', 'BodyText2', 'BodyText3', 'BodyText3', 'BodyText3']
```

We'll make the values smaller so we can fit them on the screen, while preserving the relationships:

```
index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
lower = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
upper = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

You want a function that takes those three lists and gives you

```
uniq = [1, 4, 4]
dups = [2, 5, 6]
```

Already we see a small issue - do you want only the first one to be considered unique?  Why is 1 unique but not 2?  A more generic approach would be to group them all together by uniqueness and decide later what to do with all the groups (e.g. choose the first).

We'll ignore anything about requests, because it doesn't really matter for your problem.

## Solution

What you are requesting is just a simple grouping, we can use a dict for that, with the unique portions as keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict
groups = defaultdict(list)  # Could be set, but you want order it seems
for i, low, up in zip(index, lower, upper):  # Gives us (1, 'a', 'A'), (2, ...), ...
   groups[(low, up)].append(i)
```

We now have ids grouped by your uniqueness constraint

```
>>> dict(groups)
{('a', 'A'): [1, 2], ('b', 'B'): [3], ('c', 'C'): [4, 5, 6]}
```

Since you want the first ones in one list and the rest in another, we can extract them:

```
uniq = []
dups = []
for vals in groups.values():
    for dup in vals[1:]:
        uniq.append(vals[0])
        dups.append(dup)
```

and voila:

```
>>> uniq
[1, 4, 4]
>>> dups
[2, 5, 6]
```

Note that we will discard the above since it was just an intermediate step for what you actually wanted (and we already have), in groups:

```
for vals in groups.values():
   first = vals[0]
   for dup in vals[1:]:
       mark_as_duplicate(first, dup)  # Where this is your api logic
```

---

Per follow up question in comments:

You are generating some json to send to your request like this

```
for first, one_of_rest in zip(stuff):
    body = {'requestId': first, "addRelatedEmails": [{"id": one_of_rest, "name": "EMAIL"}]}
    <do api stuff>
```

You should instead do it like this

```
for vals in groups.values():
   first = vals[0]
   rest = vals[1:]
   if rest:
       related = [{"id": item, "name": "EMAIL"} for item in rest]
       body = {'requestId': first, "addRelatedEmails": related}
       <do api stuff>
```

Comment: Hi @Cireo, thank you for your help! It seems to be 100% what I was looking for. It works perfectly fine and `groups` output is as expected. However, when I run this loop: `for vals in groups.values():` it throws error `NameError: name 'mark_as_duplicate' is not defined`. Would you know how can I fix this one? thank you!

Comment: Yes, see my comment on the end of the line. You would need to implement that logic yourself, it looks like you are doing some API calls.  I think you want `requestId` to be filled with the first argument, and `addRelatedEmails` to take the second.  It also looks like you could fill them all in one api call instead of looping, which would be faster and easier, e.g. some kind of `if len(vals) > 1:  mark_all_as duplicate(vals[0], vals[1:])`

Comment: I edited my post and added some extra information to explain my situation better. I think once I will have uniqueIds and duplicateIds organized on two lists as I presented in the last paragraph of my question, then I will be able to pass it successfully to my API. However, I'm struggling to prepare those lists in such way. Would you know how I can achieve this? thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: Take a look now?

Answer (score 1):

@Cireo got it right except for this part:

```py
uniq = []
dups = []
for vals in groups.values():
    uniq.append(vals[0])
    dups.extend(vals[1:])
```

You need to change it to:

```py
uniq = []
dups = []
for vals in groups.values():
    for i in range(1, len(vals)):
        uniq.append(vals[0])
        dups.append(vals[i])
```

After that you will have your 2 lists: `uniq` and `dups`
[image]

Comment: great help! Thanks a lot Karol! I will go through both answers and try to learn this for the future :)

Comment: Good catch @KarolZak.  Should I incorporate your answer into mine?  I don't really care about the uniq/dups because constructing them in the first place is an XY problem

Comment: You sure can add it there @Cireo. I modified that for loop because it seems like this is what Baobab1988 originally requested. I would have added this answer as a comment to your solution but I didn't have required 50 rep back then so I posted it as a separate answer :)